# How do I ensure that I am using the same session for multiple HTTP call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, net-http

Let's say that I am calling the following code from inside a loop with a 1-second sleep/delay between each iteration and the URL is an API. How do I make sure that Net::HTTP is using the same API session for all the calls? I know the documentation says Net::HTTP.new will try to reuse the same connection. But how do I verify that? Is there a session ID that I can pull out of Net::HTTP?

```
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)

url = URI(url)

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request["Accept"] = 'application/json'
request["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
request["Authorization"] = @auth_key
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'

request.body = request_body.to_json if request_body
response = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*double check the following against the ruby version you are running on*

For one, I don't think there is any session ID *from what I can see* which would be quite a useful feature. Next, looking at the source code, we see the variable setting in `lib/net/http.rb` in such methods as:

```
def do_finish
  @started = false
  @socket.close if @socket
  @socket = nil
end

# Returns true if the HTTP session has been started.
def started?
  @started
end

# Finishes the HTTP session and closes the TCP connection.
# Raises IOError if the session has not been started.
def finish
  raise IOError, 'HTTP session not yet started' unless started?
  do_finish
end
```

Where do_finish sets the instance variable `@socket` to nil and `@socket` is used as a BufferedIO instance to run HTTP requests through

So I would write an override method for the `finish` method and raise an alert when it calls on `do_finish`.

Looking through the comments `start` is the safest bet to use the same session, so you could use a start block and compare the id of the instance variable does not change

```
Net::HTTP.start(url) do |http|
  before = http.instance_variable_get(:@socket)
  loop do
    instance_var = http.instance_variable_get(:@socket)
    break unless before == instance_var
  end
end
```

Comment: seems a nice solution. Do you think it could work also in a case is a proxy that can't keep alive the connection? In that case maybe, the server may still keep the TCP connection, that means it does not call `finish`, and may open another connection to respond to the HTTP request coming from the proxy that starts a new connection. The problem is that with HTTP 1/1 the connection is kept alive for performance reason there is not guaranties that this is always possible.